# How to add tags to existing azure resources using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

I have created number of resources in azure via portal. how to add the tags to each existing resource using PowerShell or CLI?

Answer (score 7):

**AZURE POWERSHELL**
To add new tag you use `New-AzTag`.

```
New-AzTag -ResourceId $resource.id -Tag $tags
```

To add tags to a resource that already has tags, use `Update-AzTag`.

```
Update-AzTag -ResourceId $resource.id -Tag
```

**AZURE CLI**
The az tag create replaces all tags on the resource, resource group, or subscription.

```
az tag create --resource-id $resource --tags
```

To add tags to a resource that already has tags, use az tag update.

```
az tag update --resource-id $resource --operation Merge --tags Dept=Finance Status=Normal
```

This [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-resources?tabs=json) gives you more details.

Comment: Yonly, If it is possible provide the sample script for to add the tags to existing azure resources using for loop concept.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PowerShell script to update the tag to the resource which are null

```html
connect-azaccount 
$resources=Get-AzResource | Where-Object Tags -eq $null  ##list all the resource whose tags are empty
$resources=Get-AzResourceGroup | Where-Object Tags -eq $null ##list all the resources at resource group level whose tags are empty
$resources | ForEach-Object { New-AzTag -Tag @{ "Env"="test" } -ResourceId $_.ResourceId }
```

Comment: Venkatesh, Is it possible to get the list of azure resources whose tags are empty based  on the resource group name?

Comment: @Pradeep - you can use the below command to list the resources under a resource group  that has empty tag value 

Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName <resource-groupname> | Where-Object Tags -eq $null

Here is the sample screen shot for reference 
https://i.imgur.com/iLJN2lj.png