# Azure: How To Bulk Tag with PowerShell Using CSV

Tags: azure, tagging

My PowerShell is VERY rusty, so please bear with me.  I've been tasked to bulk tag Azure Resources based on CSV data, specifically Azure VM's.  In this CSV are 3 headers (VMName, TagName, TagValue).  I've tried to automate this task with PowerShell and no matter how I format the code, I keep falling short.  Can someone help me clear this up or perhaps point me in the direction of a known working PS script that will help me accomplish this?

`

```
Connect-AzAccount -TenantId ''
Set-AzContext -Subscription ''

$Import = Import-Csv -Path '...\Tags.csv' |
  ForEach-Object {
    $_.psobject.properties | 
      ForEach-Object {Set-Variable -Name $_.Name -Value $_.Tags}
        foreach ($Name in $Import) {
          $Tag = $_.Name.Tags
          $Tag.Add($_.Tags)
          Set-AzResource -ResourceId $Name.ResourceId -Tag -Force
        }
}
```

`

I've tried a hash table and a fully customized script.  It either only applies the Tag Name and not the Tag Value, and it needs both, or it shoots off error after error.  Microsoft seems to want bulk tagging at the subscription and resource group level, so it's a bit difficult to get this right specific to resources.  In the end, I want the script to read the server name in Row 1 Column 1, find that resource in Azure, and create the Tag using the Tag Name (Row 1 Column 2) and Tag Value (Row 1 Column 3).

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68564399/how-to-add-tags-to-existing-azure-resources-using-powershell#:~:text=AZURE%20POWERSHELL%20To%20add%20new%20tag%20you%20use%20New%2DAzTag%20.&text=To%20add%20tags%20to%20a,tags%2C%20use%20Update%2DAzTag%20.&text=AZURE%20CLI%20The%20az%20tag,%2C%20resource%20group%2C%20or%20subscription.&text=resource%20%2D%2Dtags-,To%20add%20tags%20to%20a%20resource%20that,tags%2C%20use%20az%20tag%20update.

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to get this work using `New-AzTag`. Below is the complete script that worked for me.

```
$Import = Import-Csv -Path 'Tags.csv'
foreach($I in $Import) {
    $Resource = Get-AzResource -Name $I.VMName
    $TagName=$I.TagName
    $TagValue=$I.TagValue
    New-AzTag -ResourceId $Resource.ResourceId -Tag @{"$TagName"="$TagValue"}
}
```

*RESULTS:*

***Tags.csv***

[image]

***In portal***

[image]